# Is there a way to use formatISOLocal for multiple date inputs

Tags: javascript, html, formatdatetime

I have multiple date input fields and each of them need to have the same functionality. The date input starts from the current day and only allows for a selection up to one year from the current date. The function works fine for the first box but no matter what I try, I can't get it to work on all of them concurrently. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker2">
<input type="date" id="datepicker3">


<script>
// Formt date as YYYY-MM-DD
function formatISOLocal(d) {
  let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  return d.getFullYear()+'-'+z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

window.onload = function() {
  let inp = document.querySelector('#datepicker1');
  let d = new Date();
  inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
  inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
  inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);
  // Debug
  console.log(inp.outerHTML);
}

</script>
```

[And link to Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yqe1ufmL/)

Comment: You are only selecting one of your datepickers with `document.querySelector('#datepicker1')`, so that is why your code is not affecting the other two.

Comment: I think I was able to work out a solution on my own http://jsfiddle.net/e18q6tyk/